Set different values of the same parameter for different instances of the same node
It is my first post so correct me if I'm doing something wrong :)
I created two instances of the same node:
<node pkg="first_project" name="odom_to_tf_gps_node" type="odom_to_tf" output="screen">

    <remap from="input_odom" to="gps_odom"/>

    <param name="root_frame"  type="string" value="root" />
    <param name="child_frame" type="string" value="child_gps_odom" />

  </node>

  <node pkg="first_project" name="odom_to_tf_wheel_node" type="odom_to_tf" output="screen">

    <remap from="input_odom" to="odom"/>

    <param name="root_frame"  type="string" value="root" />
    <param name="child_frame" type="string" value="child_wheel_odom" />

  </node>

I want to do:
n.getParam("/root_frame",  root_frame);
n.getParam("/child_frame", child_frame); 

Before /root_frame and /child_frame i should add /odom_to_tf_gps_node in one case and odom_to_tf_wheel_node in the other. How can i do that?
